# Laravel: Model Events when no changes in Provider

Tags: laravel, eloquent, provider

When updating user model ( `user::update()` ) it triggers "Model Events":

1. `User::updating`
2. `User::updated`

Only if there're some value changes, Is there a way to trigger another "Event" if there's no changes? thanks

```
//Provider

public function boot()
{
    User::updated(function ($user) {
        //do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the model has changed using the `isDirty()` method, and fire an event manually.. for example:

```
User::updating(function ($user) {
    if ( ! $user->isDirty())
    {
        event(...);
    }    
});
```

Example of `isDirty()`

```
$user = App\User::first();
$user->isDirty();          //false
$user->name = "Test";
$user->isDirty();          //true
```

but do this before `updated` I guess you should be using the `updating` event here.

Comment: I need to use `User::updated` because logic in provide, and it doesn't invoke at all when no changes

Comment: but `updated` is fired after the changes have been persisted.. so if that makes sense to you then try it :)

Comment: yes, I get your point, Is there any way to monitor "un changed" situation from provider, because `user::updating` doesn't work in porvider

Comment: You can use `$user->isDirty()` out of the events, before you call `save()` on the model. Does not have to be within the observer.

Comment: @mwafi, what happened friend, did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Use `saving` and `saved` events in that case.

Both events are trigged each time the `save` method is called,
regardless of whether something has changed on the model.

For `updating` and `updated` events, a change on the model attributes is required, otherwise Laravel skip this events.

Here an example to visualise it and show the order of events:

```
$user = User::create();

$user->save();

$user->name = 'test';
$user->save();

$user->save();
```

And here the order of events:

```
saving
creating
created
saved

saving
saved

saving
updating
updated
saved

saving
saved
```