# Updated function is not fired inside a model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model like this:

```
class Equipment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,softDeletes;
    protected $table = 'equipments';
    protected $fillable = ['station_id', 'parent_id', 'code', 'name', 'description', 'creator_id','deletor_id','updator_id'];
    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

 //it doesn't called at all!
        static::updated(function (Model $model) {
            \Log::error('calling refreshTree');
            $model->refreshTree();
        });


        static::created(function (Model $model) {
            $model->refreshTree();
        });



        static::deleted(function (Model $model) {
            $model->refreshTree();
        });

    }


    public function refreshTree(){
        \Log::error('refreshTree');
        $equipment = DB::table('equipments')->get();
        $treeData = $this->generateTree($equipment);

        $jsonData = json_encode($treeData);
        Redis::set(config('redis.EquipmentTree'),$jsonData);
    }

    private function generateTree($data, $parentId = 0) {
        $tree = [];

        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if ($item->parent_id == $parentId) {
                $children = $this->generateTree($data, $item->id);


                $node = [
                    'id' => $item->id,
                    'text' => $item->name,
                    'editURL'=>route('dashboard.basic-info.equipments.edit',['id'=>$item->id]),
                    'children' => $children
                ];
                if(count($children) <= 0)
                    unset($node['children']);

                array_push($tree, $node);
            }
        }

        return $tree;
    }

}
```

But when I created model, `created` function is fired but when I updated a model, `updated` function didn't fired:

```
           //Equipment::where('id',$id)->update(['parent_id'=>$recordTarget['id']]); //it doesn't worked
//also I try it:
            $equipment = Equipment::find($id);
            $equipment->parent_id = $recordTarget['id'];
            $equipment->save();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Model Events when no changes in Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199303/laravel-model-events-when-no-changes-in-provider) --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75211013/10542740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a Query builder instance or mass updating the event listener doesn't trigger even if you target only one row.

```
Equipment::where('id',$id) //right here you get a Builder instance
    ->update([]); //will not trigger the event listener as it is a mass update
```

To trigger it you need to use the model instance

```
Equipment::where('id',$id)->first() //This returns a model instance
    ->update([]); //will trigger the event listener as it is a single instance update
```

this is alse equivalent to

```
$equipment = Equipment::find($id);
$equipment->parent_id = ..;
$equipment->save();
```

and as you can see, [calling update() on a model](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L989) is different from [calling update() on the query builder](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Query/Builder.php#L3412)

When you think about it, to trigger the events, the code needs an instance of the model to work with it as in `static::updated(function (Model $model) {`.
If your query was different, for example `Equipment::where('id','>',$id)`, to handle all the events it would need to query all the affected rows, generate the model instance for them and then call the event with those models.

It will sink the performance.

But if there is no other way you can do it explicitly

```
$equipments = Equipment::where('id','>',$id)->get();
foreach ($equipments as $equipment) {
    $equipment->update(['parent_id'=>$recordTarget['id']]);
}
```

Comment: also if the `parent_id` did not actually change, the updated event will not trigger.